# nginx url redirect to custom url

Tags: django, nginx

I have a domain binging a IP:

`a.a.com -> 1.1.1.1`

In `1.1.1.1` has a nginx , for access `a.a.com/bbb/` to `2.2.2.2`'s django service.

`

```
#1.1.1.1
server {
    listen 8090;
   server_name localhost;
   location /bbb/ {
      proxy_pass 2.2.2.2:8000;
   }
}
```

`

when I input `a.a.com/bbb/`, I can access, it's ok.

But when Django login's session timeout , It automatic redirect `a.a.com:8090/bbb/`.

I want to ask how to automatic redirect `a.a.com/bbb/`.

ps. the 8090 port cant access

Sorry my poor English , Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `proxy_redirect off`:

```
location /bbb/ {
   proxy_pass 2.2.2.2:8000;
   proxy_redirect off;
}
```

`proxy_redirect off` tells nginx that, if the backend returns an HTTP redirect, it should leave it as is. (By default, nginx assumes the backend is stupid and tries to be smart; if the backend returns an HTTP redirect that says "redirect to http://localhost:8000/somewhere", nginx replaces it with something similar to "http://yourowndomain.com/somewhere", or, in your case, "http://yourowndomain.com:8090/somewhere". Django is smart enough so there is no need for nginx to do such things.)

Comment: yeah，you are right. But my problem's answer is : The old automatic redirect url is a.a.com/bbb, change it to a.a.com/bbb/  , it is ok! Thank you.